# How to make my Fortran loop faster with BLAS - Matrix vector multiplication

Tags: optimization, fortran, blas

I would like to optimize for speed the following Fortran code

```
DO ii = 1, N
  A (:,:) = A (:,:) + C (ii) * B (:,:, ii )
ENDDO
```

with `A(M,M)` dimension and `B(M,M)` dimension.

I was thinking of use BLAS

```
DO jj=1,M
  CALL zgemm('n', 'n', 1, M, N, cone, C(:), cone, B (jj,:, : ),&
       N, czero, A(:,:), cone )
ENDDO
```

but this does not look very efficient as I still have a loop. Is it possible to use increment and how?

In my case N is always > M

Comment: GE**MM**? That is a GE **M**atrix **M**atrix. Did you want GE**MV** or similar? (GE **M**atrix **V**ector)

Comment: Yes in this case I want matrix-vector (GEMV). I read somewhere that for some reason using GEMM for matrix-vector was somewhat faster than GEMV. But in any case, I'm open to any fast solution.

Comment: I don't get what you are doing, actually.  Whay your B(N,N) has three indexes?

Comment: @VladimirF I think OP would like to know how to efficiently calculate `\sum_{k=1}{N} B_{i,j,k} c_{k}` using something like "GE TV (GE Tensor Vector)", i.e., to contract only over the last index...

Comment: @ewcz : Exactly. So far, I've tried zgemv but its not very fast and the fastest is using zaxpy. Is it possible to do better?

Comment: Yes, AXPY actually looks like the most natural choice for the operation you do. Especially if your CPU supports vectorized fused add-multiply instructions. You can always write you own hand-optimized assembly or C vector intrinsics code tailored for your loop nest....

Comment: And obviously, any timing will depend on the BLAS implementation you use, which you don't report. Is it MKL? GotoBLAS? reference Netlib?

Comment: @sponce perhaps this might be of interest - http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.2100